# Syntax error using primary key script generated in SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I'm trying to move a primary key from one database (SQL Server 2000) to another database. In the original database I have a primary key that I've used SSMS to script this to a new query window:

```
USE [DatabaseName_Test]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tbl_itinerary_item] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl_itinerary_item] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [activity_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

All I did was change the database:

```
USE [DatabaseName]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tbl_itinerary_item] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl_itinerary_item] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [activity_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

The error I get is

> *Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 5 Line 5:
>
>   Incorrect syntax near '('.*

What am I missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert Single SQLSERVER 2005 Script to a SQL SERVER 2000 script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9925385/convert-single-sqlserver-2005-script-to-a-sql-server-2000-script)

Comment: Are both databases of the same version?

Comment: AFAIK this part is understood on SQLServer 2005 for the first time : WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON)

Comment: Yeah, @Pondlife has a good link to look at.

Comment: @Pondlife I think you're right - I simplified and it worked (solution below).

Comment: @Macness Yes, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418082/sql-server-2005-generated-create-table-script-not-working) is actually an even better one to look at, because it gives a solution too (how to tell SSMS to generate SQL2000-compatible scripts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to simplify your sql like this:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tbl_itinerary_item] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl_itinerary_item] PRIMARY KEY 
(
    [activity_id] ASC
)ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: That certainly did the trick. The script was overcomplicating things. I work in both a SQL 2000 and 2008 R2 environment so the script seems to be more in line with options that can be used by 2005. *I think*